# Objective C syntax for updating SKMutableTexture

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have some great code for manipulating pixels in a `skmutabletexture`, but it's in Swift which I'm not into yet.

90% of it I can translate into Objective C but not the creation of `rgbaPtr` and `rgbaBufferPtr`. Is there an equivalent way to sort these out using the `struct` format in Objective C? Or is this method specific to Swift?

My code (In Swift):

```
struct RGBA {
    let r: UInt8
    let g: UInt8
    let b: UInt8
    let a: UInt8
}

 texture.modifyPixelData { (pixelData, lengthInBytes) in
            // Assume that the memory of the mutable texture is bound to a tightly packed 4 element UInt32 struct.
            let rgbaPtr = pixelData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: RGBA.self)
            
            // Calculate the number of texture elements in the texture based on the byte count.
            let pixelCount = Int(lengthInBytes / MemoryLayout<RGBA>.stride)
            
            // Create a buffer pointer to more conveniently mutate the texture data.
            let rgbaBufferPtr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: rgbaPtr, count: pixelCount)
            
            // Iterate through the pixels and update them individually.
            for index in 0..pixelCount {
                
                // Calculate the row and column in the pixel (origin is bottom left corner)
                let row = index / width
                let column = index % width
                
                if row > 10 && column > 10 {
                    let myColor = RGBA(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1)
                    
                    // Assign the color to the pixel.
                    rgbaBufferPtr[index] = myColor
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not that into Swift either, but I think those are just Swift's clumsy way of handling pointers, which is really easy to do in Objective-C. I'll post what I think into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this - a really quick one, you need to complete the ... .

What you see is Swift's way of dealing with pointers, which comes natural to Objective-C, so it is in fact more direct.

```
struct RGBA
{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
};

void modifyPixedData ( struct RGBA * pixelData, NSUInteger lengthInBytes )
{
    // Now you can just use it
    struct RGBA myColor;

    myColor.red   = ...;
    myColor.green = ...;
    myColor.blue  = ...;
    myColor.alpha = ...;

    NSUInteger width = ...;
    NSUInteger pixelCount = lengthInBytes / sizeof ( struct RGBA );

    for ( NSUInteger index = 0; index < pixelCount; index ++ )
    {
        // Calculate the row and column in the pixel (origin is bottom left corner)
        NSUInteger row = index / width;
        NSUInteger column = index % width;

        if ( row > 10 && column > 10 )
        {
            * ( pixelData + index ) = myColor;
        }
    }
}
```

There are also many ways to do this, you could e.g. also do

```
pixelData[ index ] = myColor;
```

or you could loop over it with a pointer, which is very natural and efficient, e.g.

```
    struct RGBA * end = pixelData + lengthInBytes;

    NSUInteger row    = 0;
    NSUInteger column = 0;

    while ( pixelData < end )
    {
        if ( row > 10 && column > 10 )
        {
            * pixelData = myColor;
        }

        pixelData ++;
        row ++;

        if ( row == width )
        {
            row = 0;
            column ++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow @skaak thanks! Sure does look a lot simpler. One thing about `pixelData` though, it's a pointer given by the Xcode function: `[BScanTexture modifyPixelDataWithBlock:^(void *pixelData, size_t lengthInBytes) {` (Objective C translation). `pixelData` is arranged in memory as a linear collection of `uint8_t` values and not already in `struct` layout. The Swift code has a nifty way of handling these as  struct by the way it creates  `rgbaPtr`. I'm not married to that if its more complexity but is this doable in an efficient fashion in Objective C?

Comment: Since you are working with pointers you have considerable freedom. You could treat those 4x8 bit values as e.g. a 32bit integer and it will be very efficient. The struct is just a neat way to access the components and does not really add overhead so I'd keep it. Or rather, if you access the members of that 32b integer through the struct, ie the struct is useful to you, keep it.